# Were there ever any plans to have Picard be Wesley's real father?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

[image]

Were there ever plans on *The Next Generation* to have a "reveal" where we find out that Picard is Wesley's actual father, rather than Jack Crusher?

In my research, I came across old murmurings on fan boards indicating that such a storyline had indeed been considered.  However, no evidence was given.  **I am looking for an actual statement by writers, producers, or other individuals close to *The Next Generation*.**

Comment: I seriously doubt it.   It would destroy the heroism of Picard (and Dr. Crusher).   This is not a likely storyline, unless it was in an alternate timeline or there was some very heroic reason that Dr. Crusher and Picard both covered it up.   Plus right from the beginning Picard hates Wesley, so he couldn't have any suspicions right from the start.   I just don't see how this could fit in.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Fans in a few different forums have speculated that it *was* at least considered.  Picard may have been distant to Wesley on purpose.

Comment: That's so much more interesting than how that actually played out.

Comment: But Roddenberry wouldn't have stood for it - in his mind, mankind had all of this kind of stuff worked out to perfection.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens : His influence waned though, and he died during Season 5.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens : But whether or not he stood for it, I want to know if the idea was actually floated behind the scenes...even if it went down like a lead balloon.  As I said, I have seen unsubstantiated claims that there was talk behind the scenes of this. I want specific statements.

Comment: @N_Soong: Thanks for checking that!  I wonder about later ideas, especially after Roddenberry's influence began to wane.

Comment: @Praxis I just deleted the comment because when I read further down about Beverly Crusher in the Bible it showed that she was familiar with Picard...

Comment: @ThePopMachine: “right from the beginning Picard hates Wesley” — I think Picard is mainly uncomfortable around children.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: ...which would make sense if he'd fathered an illegitimate child of his own, right?

Comment: Everyone:  I'm certainly not saying they can't have considered it.  Obviously if they did, they (rightly IMO) rejected it.

Comment: That would have been a different show, much closer to DS9. Closer to Battlestar...

Comment: Actually, it was ***always*** planned that Vader was Wesley's father.

Comment: a plot point like this would certainly fill in some blanks - such as why Picard dislikes/is freaked out by children so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [TNG Companion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743457986) Wesley according to Gene Roddenberry was never supposed to be Picards son. In fact as originally written, Beverly Crusher was a very minor role, while Wesley was a main character. They were supposed to focus on how Wesley's father had died due under Picards command.

It appears as the writers fleshed out Beverly's character they decided to add a love interest between her and Picard, which is what lead many to assume that Picard was secretly the father, however, according to this book there is no mention of this ever being planned.

Basically we know from the start that Wesley was not intended to be Picards son, and we know that in the end he ended up not being Picards son. At most now we are dealing with a rumor of someone changing the back story which never panned out. As you've stated Praxis there are only mentions of this on forums, no interviews, or books containing this idea that Picard was going to be Wesley's father.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for working on this, @Himarm.  I usually wait a couple of days to accept, but given that the question has been around for a little while, I'm not expecting other answers.  Answer gratefully accepted.

Comment: @Praxis i dug pretty deep for this, and with the popularity of this idea/theory, i cant believe there are no interviews with a writer about it linked anywhere, leading me to believe it must have always been a rumor otherwise we would have a documented source to work with.